# Download files from Azure website using Azure Server Explorer inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure

In Visual Studio 2013, I can go to Server Explorer, expand the Azure > Websites node and browse my websites. Is it also possible to download the files somehow from this panel? E.g., I am interested in my ELMAH logs inside App_Data and would like to download them from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Azure has a mechanism for streaming logs within VS.  You may have to move from ELMAH to using the Tracing capabilities in the .NET framework (System.Diagnostics namespace).  check out this link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Comment: another streaming logs link: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingDiagnosticsTraceLoggingFromTheAzureCommandLinePlusGlimpse.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only view file contents from the remote server but cannot download.  See here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remoteview

It may be that you can view the ELMAH log if it's recognised by Visual Studio, otherwise I'd recommend looking at writing your ELMAH log to SQL Server instead.

Comment: Hopefully that will be added in some future update, WebMatrix can do that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

View only from Visual Studio 2015 | View | Server Explorer.

To download files and log streams etc. use Kudu.

https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/

To download web site files.  Kudu | Debug console | CMD, click on site, click on wwwroot, click on the downloadArrow Icon on the left of the wwwroot folder - or a log file or log folder of your choosing.